# fastest way to compare two columns with different data types

Tags: sql, t-sql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I have two tables that I need to join over a linked server, but I have a problem with the source data that I am stuck with for now.

The column names that I need to join on are `account_number` and `member_number` respectively.

My issue is that `account_number` is a `varchar(10)` and is always padded with leading zeros, but `member_number` is a `varchar(12)` (don't ask why, the last 2 are never used) but is not padded with leading zeros.

If we say that `account_number` is in `A` and `member_number` is in `B`, I have come up with the following solutions:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  A INNER JOIN B 
  ON CAST(A.account_number AS BIGINT) = CAST(B.member_number AS BIGINT)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM 
  A INNER JOIN B 
  ON A.account_number = RIGHT('0000000000'+B.member_number, 10)
```

The problem is that they are super slow!

It must be the fact that the functions are forcing table scans, but I'm not sure what else to do about this. Is there any way to do this comparison that is faster? Maybe with some variation of `like` or something?

Comment: have you considered it might be insufficient permissions to access statistics on the remote server? what version of SQL Server?

Comment: @MitchWheat this is SQL server 2012

Comment: @MitchWheat SP3. It is not just me experiencing the slowness. It was actually the DB admin running the query who complained to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way is to create a computed column so they are of the same types and then build an index on that column.  Something like:

```
alter table b add account_number as ( RIGHT('0000000000'+B.member_number, 10) );

create index b_acount_number on b(account_number);
```

Then run the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B 
     ON A.account_number = b.account_number;
```

That is probably the fastest you can get.

Comment: Computed column, needs to be persisted.

Comment: @FLICKER . . . The column only has to be declared as persistent if it is imprecise.  This doesn't use floating point numbers, so it seems to be precise and hence can be used as a key for an index.  But, declaring it to be persistent does not harm, given that the goal is to index the column.

Comment: You are right. I thought to have index, it should be persisted. Thanks